# How to fix jest window.alert or null error in vuejs test utils?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I want to test my vue components, but i ran into some damn crazy errors, which i did what people like using jsdom, didn't fix it, and keeps showing these errors:

```
  console.error node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Not implemented: window.alert
```

or

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"
```

I have a Header component, which its mounted is :

```
    methods: {
.
.
.
      addEventHandler(...args: any) {
        addEventHandler(...args);
      }
    },
mounted() {
  this.addEventHandler('.dej_search', 'enter', '.dej_suggestion .active-item', this.enterSection);
  //@ts-ignore
  this.addEventHandler('', 'ctrl+f||f3', 'GeneralSearch', id => document.getElementById(id).focus());
}
```

and the eventhandler code is below:

```
//addEventHandler.js:
import Vue from "vue"
import {keyboardCodes} from "@/utils/keyboardCodes";


const {enter, f, f3} = keyboardCodes;
export const addEventHandler = (domSelector = '',
                                event = '',
                                data = '',
                                eventHandler = (item) => {
                                }
) => {
  let dom = domSelector !== '' ? document.querySelector(domSelector) : window;
  switch (event) {
    case "enter":
      dom.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
        let key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
        if (key === enter) {
          eventHandler(data);
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
      break;
    case "ctrl+f||f3":
      dom.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        let key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
        if (key === f3 || (e.ctrlKey && key === f)) {
          eventHandler(data);
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
      break;
    default:
      console.log("event ....");
      break;
  }
};
```

As you can see i also used the jsdom, but i didnt fix the problem, and i really am confused to how should i fix these problems and do some unit test without pain in jest framework.

```
//header.test.js

import {mount, shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import Header from "../../../src/views/pages/Panel/Header";
import {JSDOM}  from "jsdom";

const dom = new JSDOM()
document = dom.window.document;
window = dom.window;
window.alert = jest.fn();

describe("mount",()=>{
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Header);
  console.log(wrapper.vm);
  console.log(wrapper.element);
});
```

How should we get rid of these errors?

.....

**update**

I could fix the window.alert error. because of jest which doesnot support or in anotherway it is not possible to test ui in the cli, so some functionalties like alert cannot be tested or it is hard to test which is mentioned by https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery .
so to fix the window.alert problem we can add an equal implementation or empty one just to prevent test from failing:

```
window.alert = () => {};  // provide an empty implementation for window.alert
// or 
window.alert = (text) => {console.log(text)};  // provide an non-empty implementation for window.alert
```

but i really doesn't any idea how to mock the document.getElementById which i used in the addEventHandler.js to prevent such error for 'addEventListener' of null".
 is there any good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.alert` and several other browser-specific side effects needs to be stubbed manually. This should preferably be done with Jest, so a spy could be tracked and cleaned up:

```
jest.spyOn(window, 'alert').mockReturnValue();
```

Calls to `window.alert` can be asserted then.

If JSDOM stubbed it automatically, this would do more harm than good. This is rarely a problem because `alert` is unfriendly to UI/UX and uncommon in production code.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

means that the element doesn't exist. This probably is caused by that the component was shallowly mounted and wasn't rendered entirely, which is generally a preferable strategy for unit testing.

Either `addEventListener` method or a module with `addEventListener` can be mocked to prevent the access to DOM:

```
jest.mock('.../addEventListener', () => ({ addEventListener: jest.fn() }));
```

Calls to `addEventListener` can be asserted as well.